# How to access array elements contained in a dictionary in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have spent some time trying to search for this and I haven't found a solution. I am trying to access a specific array value in a dictionary. Below is the general code/explanation for what I want to do.

```
var dict = ["1": [1,2,3,4,5], "2": [6,7,8,9,10], "3": [11,12,13,14,15]]

//now lets say I want to access the 3rd value of dict["2"] = 8
//I have tried the following and failed

print(dict["2": [2]])
print(dict["2"][2])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way you can achieve that:

```
var dict = ["1": [1,2,3,4,5], "2": [6,7,8,9,10], "3": [11,12,13,14,15]]
let temp = dict["2"]![2]  // 8
```

Comment: Happy to help you..:)